# Fade out the canvas image after some time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to create some cloud-type effect on the image using the html 5 canvas and javascript. I draw the image using canvas above my main image but now I have to fade out the images randomly. but it does not seem to work when I try it using normal jquery fade out function below is my code.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image();

img.src = '/images/smoke-2.png';

var v = 0;
var vt = 0;
var count = 0;

img.onload = function(){
  //console.log(Math.ceil(canvas.width/70));

  var t = Math.ceil(canvas.width/5);
  var ht = Math.ceil(canvas.height/5);
    for (var w = 0; w < t; w++) {
      vt = 0;
      for (var h = 0; h < ht; h++) {
        //console.log(vt);
        context.drawImage(img, v, vt);
        vt += 5;
        count++;
      }
      v += 5;
      //console.log(v);
    }

}
```

can anybody please help me to figure it out.

fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/apatxedf/

Comment: Try writing a function on `img.complete` property with a `setTimeout()` to complete your fade out? tbh never tried this but worth trying.

Comment: Is it work for every image. cause i am printing the same image multiple times.

Comment: Can you put a stack snippet or jsfiddle with complete code to help you out please? My method only works for the current image you're holding on to `img` variable. But using jQuery i might be able to look for an alternative.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/apatxedf/ this is the fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `for loop`. You should use `setTimeout`. Try the code below according to your code.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
img = new Image();

img.src = '/images/smoke-2.png';

var v = 0;
var vt = 0;
var count = 0;

img.onload = function(){
  var t = Math.ceil(canvas.width/5);
  var ht = Math.ceil(canvas.height/5);

  var w=0, h=0;
  var timer = setTimeout(drawFunc, 1000);

  function drawFunc() {
      context.drawImage(img, v, vt);
      h++;
      vt += 5;
      count++;
      if(h==ht) {
        h=0;
        vt=0;
        w++;
        v+=5;
        if(w==t) {
          clearTimeout(timer);
        }
      }
      timer = setTimeout(drawFunc, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: why if i will use time out it will be more time consuming for me

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but I just happened to do something very similar that involved fading from a solid colour to an image so modified it for SO and OP's images (was dark with fire and lightning now light and flowers) and added comments.

Draws the image and fade-in fx using many layers, of gradients, particles and composite modes. The underlying image is slowly rotated and scaled.

```js
// create canvas and context
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.left = canvas.style.top = "0px";
canvas.style.zIndex = 100000;
canvas.style.border = "none";
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// add to DOM
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var currentLoopFunction;
var firstRun = true;
var timeoutHandle;
// resize canvas will restart animation
function resize() {
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    // stack overflow is causing problems here so have added 
    // a timers to delay the restart
    if(!firstRun){
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
        timeoutHandle = setTimeout(()=>currentLoopFunction = restart,500);
        //currentLoopFunction = restart;
    }
    firstRun = false;
}
resize();
currentLoopFunction = loadText;
const fx = {
    growRate: 1, // number of pixels per frame on average that the smoke image grows by
    smokeMove: 0.01, // rotate the smoke to make it look like its is swirling
    ringDist: 0.85, // distance from image center to stop movement of smoke outward. As a fraction of radius ofa canvas bounding circle 
    centerPull: 0.125, // pull all smoke in towards the center of canvas at start
    scaleRange: 5, // the close smoke is to center the larger it is. This sets the max center scale multiplier
    pCount: 100, // Approx number of particles to render
    flowerScaleGrow: 0.03, // slowly grow flower image to normal scale
    flowerScaleStart: 0.9, // scale of flower at start
    flowerScaleEnd: 1.3, // scale of flower towards end. Will never get to this value
    flowerRotate: 0.01, // rate to rotate flower
    flowerRotateStart: -0.6, // Startng angle of flower image
    flowerRotateEnd: 0.0, // end angle of flower image
    sCurveSlope: 1.2, // slope of s curve at origin (not real slope) must be > 1 and smaller valuesreduce the rate of change
    // this controls flower rotate and grow
    globalAlphaRate: 0.01, // controls the rate global alpha is reduced
}

function sCurve(x) {
    return (2 / (1 + Math.pow(fx.sCurveSlope, -x))) - 1;
}
var imageAspect = 1;
var imageScaleToFill = 1;
var globalAlpha = 1;
var frameCounter; // counts frames
var smoke = new Image;
var flowers = new Image;
var imageCount = 0; // count the image as they load and used to stage setup

// Two radial gradients from transparent white in center to white at edges
// first one is smaller and a softer transition
// The second one is used to cover corners if display canvas aspect ratio is extreme
var ringGrad;
var ringGrad1;


// load the images
smoke.src = "http://www.emqubeweb.com/smoke-2.png";
flowers.src = "http://www.emqubeweb.com/flower.png";
smoke.onload = flowers.onload = function() {
    imageCount += 1
};
// draws a particle
function drawImage(p) { // p is particle
    ctx.setTransform(p.scale, 0, 0, p.scale, p.x, p.y);
    ctx.rotate(p.angle);
    ctx.globalAlpha = p.alpha * globalAlpha;
    ctx.drawImage(smoke, -smoke.width / 2, -smoke.height / 2);
}

// object that controls particles.
var particles = {
    items: [], // array of particles
    update() { // updates the scale position, rotation and alpha of particle
        var i, p, cw, ch, dx, dy, dist, distMax, area, r;

        // get canvas center
        cw = canvas.width / 2;
        ch = canvas.height / 2;
        distMax = Math.sqrt(cw * cw + ch * ch) * fx.ringDist; // extend diagonal max dist from center

        // do each particle in turn
        for (i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            p = this.items[i];

            // get vector from center to particle and normalise it
            dx = p.x - cw;
            dy = p.y - ch;
            dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) + 0.001; // the 0.001 added is to stop / by zero
            dx /= dist;
            dy /= dist;

            // move outward. The futher out the slowre it moves
            p.x += (1 - dist / distMax) * dx * (p.rand * 0.25 + 0.1);
            p.y += (1 - dist / distMax) * dy * (p.rand * 0.25 + 0.1);

            // add a little movement along the tangent to the center
            p.y -= (1 - dist / distMax) * dx * (p.rand * 0.2 + 0.1);
            p.x += (1 - dist / distMax) * dy * (p.rand * 0.2 + 0.1);

            // get the particle area
            area = (smoke.width * smoke.height) * p.scale;

            // increase area and then caculate new scale for the new area
            p.scale *= Math.sqrt(area + (Math.random() + Math.random()) * fx.growRate) / Math.sqrt(area);
            p.angle += fx.smokeMove * (p.rand * 0.5 + 0.5);

            // as particles volume increase reduce the transparency
            p.alpha = p.startVol / (area * smoke.height);
        }
    },
    draw() {
        var i;;
        for (i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            drawImage(this.items[i])
        }
    }
}

// render loading screen 
function loadText() {
    ctx.font = "32px arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText("Loading images, please wait.", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.fillText("Best viewed fullpage.", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 + 36);
 
    currentLoopFunction = wait; // set the loop function to wait
}

function blackenSmoke() {

    // so the following creates a copy of the smoke image adding some grays to give extra FX
    var smoke1 = document.createElement("canvas");
    smoke1.width = smoke.width;
    smoke1.height = smoke.height;
    smoke1.ctx = smoke1.getContext("2d");

    // add black
    smoke1.ctx.fillStyle = "#d5d";
    smoke1.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, smoke.width, smoke.height);

    // mask out black with smoke
    smoke1.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
    smoke1.ctx.setTransform(0.95, 0, 0, 0.95, smoke.width / 2, smoke.height / 2);
    smoke1.ctx.rotate(0.1);
    smoke1.ctx.drawImage(smoke, -smoke.width / 2, -smoke.height / 2);

    // draw smoke a little smaller and rotated
    smoke1.ctx.setTransform(0.93, 0, 0, 0.93, smoke.width / 2, smoke.height / 2);
    smoke1.ctx.rotate(-0.1);
    smoke1.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    smoke1.ctx.drawImage(smoke, -smoke.width / 2, -smoke.height / 2);
    smoke1.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    smoke1.ctx.drawImage(smoke1, -smoke.width / 2, -smoke.height / 2);

    // draw once more to bring up the brightness
    smoke1.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighten";
    smoke1.ctx.drawImage(smoke, -smoke.width / 2, -smoke.height / 2);
    smoke1.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    smoke1.ctx.drawImage(smoke1, -smoke.width / 2, -smoke.height / 2);

    // set the new smoke image.
    smoke = smoke1;
}
// create gradients
function createGradients(){
    ringGrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height) / 2);
    ringGrad.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,255,255,0)");
    ringGrad.addColorStop(0.2, "rgba(255,255,255,0)");
    ringGrad.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)");
    ringGrad.addColorStop(0.9, "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)");
    ringGrad.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255,255,255,1)");
    ringGrad1 = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Math.max(canvas.width, canvas.height) * 0.25);
    ringGrad1.addColorStop(0.0, "rgba(255,255,255,0.0)");
    ringGrad1.addColorStop(0.6, "rgba(255,255,255,0.0)");
    ringGrad1.addColorStop(0.7, "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)");
    ringGrad1.addColorStop(0.8, "rgba(255,255,255,0.6)");
    ringGrad1.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255,255,255,1)");
 }

// Wait for images to load
function wait() {
    if (imageCount === 2) {
        blackenSmoke();
        start();
        window.addEventListener("resize", resize);

    }
}

function restart() {
    particles.items.length = 0;
    start();
}

function start() {
    var x, y, dx, dy, px, py, dist, scale, cw, ch;

    // get the particle width and height to match the canvas
    w = canvas.width / Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(fx.pCount));
    h = canvas.height / Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(fx.pCount));

    // set the particle scale
    scale = Math.min(w / smoke.width, h / smoke.height);

    // find the center and diagonal distance from center to top left
    cw = canvas.width / 2;
    ch = canvas.height / 2;
    distMax = Math.sqrt(cw * cw + ch * ch); // extend diagonal max dist from center    

    // add particles 
    for (y = 0; y < canvas.height; y += h) {
        for (x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += w) {
            // get particle center location plus randomise by its width and height
            px = x + (Math.random() - Math.random()) * w + w / 2;
            py = y + (Math.random() - Math.random()) * h + h / 2;

            // find he vector and distance from canvas center to particle
            dx = px - canvas.width / 2;
            dy = py - canvas.height / 2;
            dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            if (dist > 5) { // if to close to center particle gets stuck so just only particles at least 5 pixels from center

                // move the particle towards the center for start position
                px -= dx * fx.centerPull;
                py -= dy * fx.centerPull;

                // The closer to the center the particle is the bigger it should be.
                // dist multiplies the scale
                dist = Math.cos((dist / distMax) * Math.PI * 0.5) * fx.scaleRange;
                // add the particle. Get the volume approximating a cubic volume for the smoke
                particles.items.push({
                    x: px,
                    y: py,
                    rand: Math.random()*0.9 + 0.1, // a constant random per particle for various fx
                    alpha: 1,
                    scale: scale * dist,
                    startVol: smoke.width * smoke.height * smoke.height * scale * dist,
                    angle: Math.random() * Math.PI * 2,
                })
            }
        }
    }

    // set the image aspect
    imageAspect = flowers.height / flowers.width;
    // changed to scale to fit use min (to fill use Math.max)
    imageScaleToFill = Math.max(flowers.height / canvas.height, flowers.width / canvas.width);
    createGradients();
    frameCounter = 0;
    currentLoopFunction = fadeIn; // function to loop
}

function fadeIn() {
    // clears canvas and renders layers
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    frameCounter += 1;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

    // white background layer
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Main image layer slowly rotated and scaled
    var scale = fx.flowerScaleStart + sCurve(frameCounter * fx.flowerScaleGrow) * (fx.flowerScaleEnd - fx.flowerScaleStart);
    globalAlpha = 1 - sCurve(frameCounter * fx.globalAlphaRate)
    ctx.setTransform(scale * imageScaleToFill, 0, 0, scale * imageScaleToFill, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(fx.flowerRotateStart + sCurve(frameCounter * fx.flowerRotate) * (fx.flowerRotateEnd - fx.flowerRotateStart));
    ctx.drawImage(flowers, -canvas.width / 2, -canvas.width * 0.5 * imageAspect, canvas.width, canvas.width * imageAspect);

    // Draw flower image again with multiply to increase the contrast
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1 - globalAlpha;
    ctx.drawImage(flowers, -canvas.width / 2, -(canvas.width / 2) * imageAspect, canvas.width, canvas.width * imageAspect);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

    // Draw the smoke particles
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    particles.update();
    particles.draw();

    // draw a white round boarder
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighten";
    ctx.setTransform(scale * scale, 0, 0, scale * scale, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = ringGrad;
    ctx.fillRect(-canvas.width, -canvas.height, canvas.width * 2, canvas.height * 2);

    //Draw smoke image over to ease the transition from white to the smokes grays
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.globalAlpha = globalAlpha;
    ctx.drawImage(smoke, -canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // flat white layer ensures that at start there is only white.
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(-canvas.width, -canvas.height, canvas.width * 2, canvas.height * 2);

    // Finnal outer ring gradient to clean up edges if image display aspect is extreme
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = ringGrad1;
    ctx.fillRect(-canvas.width, -canvas.height, canvas.width * 2, canvas.height * 2);
    if (globalAlpha < 0.001) { // when global alpha is very small (well below visible)
        currentLoopFunction = restart; // restart
    }
}
// main loop calls various functions as needed
function mainLoop() {
    currentLoopFunction();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```